# Adobe Acrobat in Wine - could not be saved - disk full

Tags: wine, adobe-acrobat

I was getting a "could not save - disk full" error in Adobe Acrobat in wine. Sometimes it would save but then it wouldn't.

(I forget the exact error message and now Acrobat is freezing and not reproducing, so go ahead and post the message in a comment for better searchability)

Answer (score 1):

I tried saving inside a folder that was in the `C:/` drive of snap acrordrdc wine, and that worked fine!